# getClientBoundingRect for conditionally rendered element with animation in Svelte

Tags: svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-transition

Given conditionally rendered div with drop-down menu. In order to calculate its position (to open it to up or down) I need to get its height and width.

Of course element doesn't get correct dimensions before the transition is done.

So question is - how do I turn off transition programmatically? Or how do I get future position of element without showing it?

```
{#if isOpened}
    <div
        bind:this={thisMenu}
        use:clickOutside
        on:click_outside={closeHandler}
        class="dropdown absolute left-100p text-gray-600 z-10 w-full animated
        rounded-lg"
        style={finalStyle}
        {isInit ?  null : transition:slide }>
        <slot name="list" />
    </div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

slide-transition uses getComputedStyle, so maybe that’s what you need. The following is copied from slide function in svelte’s repository (src/runtime/transition/index.ts). Slide-function sets those values from zero to initial value and back.

```
const style = getComputedStyle(node);
const opacity = +style.opacity;
const height = parseFloat(style.height);
const padding_top = parseFloat(style.paddingTop);
const padding_bottom = parseFloat(style.paddingBottom);
const margin_top = parseFloat(style.marginTop);
const margin_bottom = parseFloat(style.marginBottom);
const border_top_width = parseFloat(style.borderTopWidth);
const border_bottom_width = parseFloat(style.borderBottomWidth);
```

EDIT:
@bobfanger explained in comments how to make a custom `mySlide`-function and within that function there are those initial size values available. Here is a working example:

```
<script>
  import {slide} from "svelte/transition"
  let show=false 
  let d
  function mySlide(el) { 
    let s=window.getComputedStyle(d)
    console.log("mySlide",s.height)
    return slide(el, {duration:2000})
  }
</script>
<h1 on:click={()=>show=show?false:true}>Click me</h1>
{#if show}
<div bind:this={d} transition:mySlide
 style="background-color:yellow;padding:10px;border:10px solid;">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
{/if}
```

This is much simpler than to use `onMount` and `visibility` hacks.

Comment: I thought that in order to calculate of div which will be transitioned - we have to flash it out without animation. Then if user will open menu - we already know in which direction to open it.

Comment: Basically I trying to prevent scenario when menu is opened outside or viewport

Comment: I couldn’t find lifecycle method that runs after thr component is mounted and before animation starts (this is the moment when slide-function reads the initial dimensions of element). Therefore only way I find now is to set the element `visibility:hidden;position:absolute` at creation time and read the dimensions. Then set style values back to normal and let the animation run.

Comment: Here is REPL where in onMount-function the element height is retrieved (console.log) and then the element is ready for animation: https://svelte.dev/repl/57d9f664dac84921910abed394cabb5d?version=3.24.1

Comment: The `slide` in `transition: slide` is a regular javascript function. To do something before the animation starts create a `function mySlide(el) { doThing();return slide(el, {duration:})}  and apply with  <div transition:mySlide

Comment: @BobFanger thank you for a new information. I noticed that `transition:` runs `mySlide`-function only when showing `el` (animation works still both way), but `in:MySlide` and `out:mySlide` runs the function respectively.

Comment: Good to know. PS. Depending on that you need to do the https://svelte.dev/docs#Transition_events could also be an option

Comment: I tested earlier ransition events and `introstart` -event runs right before the animation runs (obviously) and then the element height is all ready zero (as it should be). 
`slide` -function reads element size before animation as an initial values and I needed access to those values. Events didn’t help with initial values, but your suggestion of custom function does exactly that. In `mySlide` -function there are those initial values available and there is no need for `onMount` and `visibility` hacks.